# How to put a file, create a file and read a file from an Android app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to develop this application which manages a patients and records list from a hospital using files to store the data.

My program reads the patients info from patients.txt, and every patient has his own file as well... if the program doesn't find it, it creates it.

Whenever I used JAVA before I relayed on BufferedReaders and the File class to read the files stored in the src folder (or the project folder created by eclipse).

With Android this doesn't seem to work... What's the relative path for an app?

Comment: Look at assets, and getFilesDir() for initialzed vs. writable data respectively.  Most people would advise storing such things as an sqlite database rather than plain files. **Keep in mind that there is a very high bar for legally handling patient data**

Comment: I know a database would be much better, but this project is to practice file management with java and string manipulation, so basically I have to stick to Files... the thing is that I need files to be readable/updatable and I understand Assets won't allow a file to be rewritten?

Comment: Assets are compiled into your apk.Save files to your app's internal directory (placed underneath `/data/data/<your-package>/files`) and have a look at `Context.getFilesDir()` for that purpose, as @ChrisStratton already told you. Remember that they can get lost when the user "clears the data" of an app, though, so you might want to save them in an external path alternatively.